# Refusing income or payment without tax liabilities

Tags: united-states, tax-law, texas, payment

I am part of a non-profit organization that is insisting on paying me for my time. For personal reasons, this payment is more costly for me to accept than to disclaim it entirely.

Is there a proper and legal way to disclaim this income and disclaim the liabilities that come with receiving this income? Is there a law in the tax code that mentions a proper way of disclaiming income?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, you can not "turn your back" on income you are entitled to receive. So the best way to avoid your problem is to make sure you are not "entitled" to that income.

If your organization feels to strongly about paying for your services, it can make a contribution to another NPC "on your behalf" or something along those lines.

Frankly, the whole thing sounds silly. Either your NPC gives up on paying you or you give up and take the money and the consequences.