# Un-Accepted Income

Tags: united-states, tax-law

In the question, [Refusing income or payment without tax liabilities](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/48185/refusing-income-or-payment-without-tax-liabilities), the accepted answer states,

> Generally speaking, you can not "turn your back" on income you are entitled to receive.

What exactly does that mean?

If I mow the grass or shovel snow for my elderly neighbor and she wants to pay me, I have to accept her money?

Let's say she wanted to pay me $20 for 31 weeks out of the year and I refused to accept.  Does she have to issue a 1099 because she thinks I was entitled to more then $600 in a calendar year?  Do I have to pay tax on it?

Please explain "income entitled to receive."

Comment: Your example does not involve a contract, and therefore no income you are *entitled* to receive. If she somehow did pay you for the work, it would then be income you *did* receive.